# Using a package file type with NSPersistentDocument

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I am creating a document-based application and I want to use NSPersistentDocument. My document will have several image assets and I would like to avoid saving the assets in the database directly. What I want is to have a package as my document type, and within it have Core Data file as well as my image assets. Then, in Core Data I would save paths to the image assets.

However when I subclass NSPersistentDocument, it seems to want to use the document file for the actual Core Data file, and I don't get the opportunity to employ a package solution.

Is it possible to use a package with NSPersistentDocument? If not, is there a preferable architecture to use? I want to stick with Core Data for this project. Thanks!